# How to authenticating Trac with MS Windows domain user when using TracStandalone as webserver

Tags: python, trac

There is a solution while using Apache as webserver.
http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindows/Advanced#AuthenticatingTracusersagainstMSWindowsdomaincontroller

How to do this with TracStandalone?

Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can do that with the built-in `tracd`.  It's a lightweight server designed for test and development.  For production purposes, it's only suitable for users with basic needs.  Anything as complex as authenticating with a Windows domain is going to need a full-featured web server like Apache that is more powerful and more configurable.